How to pass a variable struct to a constructor?
Here is a pseudo example of what I want. I'd like to be able to pass in a variety of different structs, say struct A, struct B, struct C of varying contents.
How can I do this properly?
struct wrapper_struct
{
    struct nested_struct; 

    wrapper_struct(SOME_DATA_TYPE?? c_nested_struct) //constructor
    {
        nested_struct = c_nested_struct;
    }
};

int main()
{
    wrapper_struct passedA(some_A);
    wrapper_struct passedB(some_B);
    wrapper_struct passedC(some_C);
    return(0);
}

Essentially, I'm wanting to create a function that takes ANY struct as a parameter, and within the function will create a new struct with a few general details (int strings bools w/e) then pack in the passed struct, which will ultimately be sent over a network.


Is it a closed set of structs?

The hard part here is making nested_struct a type that can hold one of the three structures, std::variant may help, and once you have that worked out, you don't pass in an A, B or C, you pass in an object of the same type as nested_struct. But.... I recommend explaining why you want to do this. There is probably a better solution to that problem that makes this problem obsolete.

@user4581301 I've updated more reasoning above.

@fdan I'm not sure what a closed set means, but assuming I know what you are referring to.. No, I'd like to be able to pass in ANY struct.

This sounds like more of a job for protobufs than building something yourself in c/c++. https://protobuf.dev/
Especially because you are talking about sending this stuff over the network as rich data structures. Also trying to be this variant thing is just going to yourself a lot of work down the road.

C++ isn't good at what you're asking for. C++ wants nice, known-at-compile time commodities so that it can optimize the  out of your code. When I'm trapped into sending around an ANYTHING, I try to make a single general structure or pass around the ultimate in general data: A string. This is a job for a weakly-typed language like Python. You lose speed, but you gain flexibility.

@user4581301 If I'm following correctly, I'd just need a set of these struct wrappers to precisely accommodate all the various structs that would need to be passed?

@HSchmale I'll look into protobufs if another solution doesnt arise. I'm sure you can tell already, but I'm new to c++ in general, so I'm trying to keep things bare bones.

I think you're in for a world of hurt trying to send these weird buffers down the wire. There's an insane number of things that need to be wrangled. You're best off using a known serialization format. As they say the best artists copy.

Side note: Sending stucts over a network connection is almost always the wrong choice. Different systems have different sizes and representations for even the most basic of types. For example, an int could be 16 bits. Or 128. They bytes could be stored most -to-least significant like a person reading left to right. Or it could be stored least to most because that's more efficient for some common computer tasks.  There can be different spacings between the structure members because different padding gives better performance on different systems. You're going to want to serialize this.

Is there a "STD" way to serialize this without importing a json library?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

There is no standard way and JSON... Zoinks. Your data as JSON can be orders of magnitude larger, and thus a lot slower to transmit and work with. Look at protocol buffers as @HSchmale recommends.

Alright, dang... Those protobuffs seem like orders of magnitude beyond my c++ knowledge lol
Ah well, I'll peruse!

Assuming all of the structs have some common attributes, I'd consider a templated constructor and enforcing required traits as needed.    You'll still need to design your protocol and the wrapper struct to allow all the structs to be safely serialised and (if sent over a network) deserialised at the other end.   There isn't some magical means in C++ which allows that to happen without effort.

@Peter The client is created inside a game engine that uses JSON to send data in a similar fashion struct --> json --> send string
I guess options are limited... I'd have to somehow read that c++ side, so I'm thinking ill be importing a json library sacrificing some speed.
This seems so janky just to send some structured data... I can't imagine making something like an MMO in early 2000s!

IDK creating my own serialization dealio might be a decent option...

When I'm writing communications between two programs, I find that it is very helpful for development and debugging to support both data-as-text (like JSON) even though that is "bloated", and (if relevant) data-as-binary.  Likewise for save file formats (JSON or XML, as well as binary).  For binary communications, my project uses Google Protocol Buffers, but it was a different dev who did that work.

This is true. I generally start with an easy-to-debug text format and migrate to binary when the need for speed arises, and sometimes it never does. That said, and purely my opinion, I still wouldn't use JSON unless the other party in the communications is written in a language where JSON is a well-supported, first-class protocol, like Python.
